# Custom recovery location in boot.img

Tags: recovery-mode, boot

I am using samsung galaxy y. I have installed a custom kernel and that kernel  has a custom recovery that boots automatically when i boot into recovery. I want to change custom recovery present in the kernel.

I unpacked boot.img and found zimage file & ramdisk.cpio.gz. Then unpacked ramdisk.cpio.gz and found many files. But I have no idea where is that custom recovery.

Please guide me its location and procedure to do so.

Comment: Could you mention the source which you followed to install that custom kernel including the links to the files? (I've doubts reserved for this question.)

Answer (score -1):

Found the recovery location in `/sbin` directory.